# EF - AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...) with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to run this query using Entity Framework in my ASP.NET MVC project but I am not succeeding. Could anyone help me do this using LINQ?

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Produtos p
WHERE p.enterpriseID = '00000000000191' and p.productId <> '14' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SimilarProducts sp WHERE sp.similarId = 
p.productId)
```

TABLES:

```
PRODUCT                        SIMILARPRODUCTS
productId|enterpriseId         id|productId|similarId
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The direct equivalent LINQ construct of SQL `NOT EXISTS (...)` is `!Any(...)`.

So

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Produtos p
WHERE p.enterpriseID = '00000000000191' and p.productId <> '14' 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SimilarProducts sp WHERE sp.similarId = 
p.productId)
```

translates to

```
from p in db.Produtos
where p.enterpriseID = "00000000000191" && p.productId != 14 
&& !db.SimilarProducts.Any(sp => sp.similarId == p.productId)
select p;
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `Contains` with `Any` which will work like `NOT EXISTS` in SQL. Like this:

```
var restuls = db.Produtos.Where(p => p.enterpriseID == '00000000000191' 
                 && p.productId != 14 
                 && !db.SimilarProducts.Any(sp =>sp.SimilarId == p.productId));
```

Comment: you were using <> for not equal to condition which linq does not support

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your answer, the logic is correct but the context of this linq are wrong in my code! The Contains only receive a single string in pameter.

Comment: @vtncgustavo - What is the context in your case?

Comment: The error is in the parameter of Contains(sp => sp.Similar Id == p.productId), it does not understand this as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

EF **Contains** => sql **in()** : iterate all items (slower)

EF **Any** => sql **exists()** : iterate until conditions return true (faster)

```
 await appDbContext.MasterTable
.Where(m => !m.DetailTable.Any(d => d.MasterId == m.Id))
.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This repeats both other answers.