# SQL TO linq in c#

Tags: c#, sql-to-linq-conversion

This code is from my sql query

```sql
SELECT Branchname
FROM Branch
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Branchname FROM vBranching 
WHERE Branch.Branchname = vBranching.Branchname AND UserName = 'xCuttiepies');
```

iwant to execute it into linq c# web api

Its look like this

```cs
var Branch = _dbcontext.Branches.Select(c => c.Branchname).ToList();
var vBranching = _dbcontext.VBranchings.Select(a => a.BranchName).ToList();
var ass = Branch.Where(!Branch.Exists(Branch == vBranching));
return Ok(vBranching);
```

In `Branch == vBranching` it says cannot convert from bool to `System.Predicate<string>`

I want to fetch the data that not exists on that different tables.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545439/ef-and-not-exists-select-1-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You souldn't be using `ToList` except right at the end, and your lambda syntax is off, and the equivalent of `EXISTS` is `Any`. You are also returning the wrong value.

```cs
var Branches =
    _dbcontext.Branches
    .Where(b => !_dbcontext.VBranchings.Any(vb =>
        vb.BranchName == b.BranchName && vb.UserName == "xCuttiepies"))
    .Select(c => c.Branchname)
    .ToList();
return Ok(Branches);
```